# Negative sampling for graph representation learning

Tags: word2vec, graphs, sampling

I was watching a lecture about graph representation learning (from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrhBZUtgG4E)) and got a little bit confusing about how they define the negative samping procedure.

In [the presentation](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-2018/handouts/09-node2vec.pdf) J. Leskovec briefly describes the famous trick with the following slide [image]

He refers to the article by Y. Goldberg for details of how this formula is derived. The problem is that formula is a little bit different (with the additional minus sign in the sigmoid):

[image]

Moreover, in their [famous article](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2013/file/9aa42b31882ec039965f3c4923ce901b-Paper.pdf) Mikolov et al defined negative sampling the same way.

I couldn't find any explaination from Leskovec or anyone about this difference. Would anyone be so kind to explain this to me?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you point. Could you explain it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the approximation in the slide isn't quite right in 2 ways:

- The Golberg/Levy & Mikolov papers have the loss function right: as in standard binary classification, the "-" sign is inside the sigmoid ($\sigma$) function, you can't pull it out and put it before the summation (that happens when you consider gradients, but that's another matter).
- Negative sampling (line 2 of your equation) was used to avoid calculating softmax (line 1) when there are many classes, as it gets expensive.
  However, they are not mathematically equivalent, i.e. the embeddings ($\mathbf{z}$'s) learn different things. That is why in word2vec (and also in comparable graph embedding models) the embeddings end up factorising *pointwise mutual information* ("PMI", see Goldberg/Levy paper) when using the marginal probability of each word/node as the *noise distribution* $P_V$.

(Note: Negative sampling is inspired by Noise Contrastive Estimation (NCE). They are not the same thing but often confused, e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/93326/116384.)